# c# encoding to PHP encoding

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

I have an ASP project in which some encoding algorithm is used to save the password. I have to convert c# code to PHP code to compare the password with my table value in SQL database.

Code used in c# for encoding is

```
MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
Byte[] hashedDataBytes;
UTF8Encoding encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
hashedDataBytes = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(encoder.GetBytes(password));
```

Now while registration, I entered the password '123456', and when I checked table Customers , password saved is 0xE10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

and column structure in the table is Password (binary(50),null).

Can any one please tell me what code should I use in PHP to compare '123456' with
0xE10ADC3949BA59ABBE56E057F20F883E00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Answer (score -1):

You have to check the method ComputeHash in the class MD5CryptoServiceProvider
and write a similiar class/method in PHP
With that bit of code, nobody can help you!